# Не работает jsoup android

Tags: android-sdk, android-studio, java, android

[Логи ошибок](http://pastebin.com/7knQjNSa). Код приложения взят с [примера](http://pastebin.com/h9M1cmgh). Если взять этот код и немного изменить под обычную яву в IDEA, то все работает. [Пример](http://pastebin.com/KcHTdCur)

Только начинаю писать под андроид, подскажите, в чем проблема ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В андроиде нельзя ходить в сеть из основного потока (`android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException`). Пользуйтесь, напр., `AsyncTask`.